# Voldemort installation: could not find tools.jar

Tags: java, cmd, voldemort

I wanted to experiment a little with Voldemort, but when installing I get the error message "could not find tools.jar", while running the 'gradlew build -x test' command.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the tools.jar listed as a dependency in your build.gradle.

This is how I do it for a local workaround, and it works perfectly for run/tests.  Be aware that if you are releasing an artifact the dependency won't be included.

```
repositories {
    flatDir dirs: System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/lib/"
}

dependencies {
    compile ":tools"
}
```

Make sure you have your JAVA_HOME environment variable set correctly.  Another option is to [directly load the classes](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html), but that's a bit more tricky.

Comment: Thanks! But now I get another error: "Could not find method compile() for arguments [:tools] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@6bbe50c9". Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: @RayoVerweij You're most likely putting it in the wrong place.  Place those 2 blocks in the root level of your *module* build.gradle file.  Alternatively, you can try putting them in the buildscript block in your root project build.gradle - this is where you would replace "compile" with "classpath" and it'll work.  I don't know your project configuration so I can't tell you which one is the correct way to do it.  Most likely it will be classpath in the buildscript closure, I'm just guessing though.